# React Native App Crashing on iOS When Recording Audio

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to record audio on iOS using a React Native app created with create-react-native-app. I am using the expo-av library to record. However, when I press "start recording", it immediately crashes. Through some console.log statements, I find that it happens after "Requesting Permissions" but before "Starting Recording". This works just fine on Android. Attached is my code. Why is this happening?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, setState} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Layout, Text, Card } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import styles from './../../util/styles';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default function Record({navigation}) {
    const [recording, setRecording] = useState();

    const REC_OPT = {
        isMeteringEnabled: true,
        android: {
          extension: '.m4a',
          outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
          audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          numberOfChannels: 1,
          bitRate: 128000,
        },
        ios: {
          extension: '.wav',
          audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_MAX,
          sampleRate: 16000,
          numberOfChannels: 1
        },
    };
  
    async function startRecording() {
        try {
            console.log('Requesting permissions... ');
            await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
            await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
                allowsRecordingIOS: true,
                playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            }); 
            console.log('Starting recording..');
            const recording = new Audio.Recording();
            await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(REC_OPT);
            await recording.startAsync(); 
            setRecording(recording);
            console.log('Recording started');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
        }
    }
  
    async function stopRecording() {
        console.log('Stopping recording..');
        setRecording(undefined);
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        const uri = recording.getURI(); 
        console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);

        const fileArray = uri.split("/");
        const filename = fileArray[fileArray.length - 1];


        const newFilepath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/" + filename;
        console.log("old filepath: ", uri, " new filepath: ", filename, " document directory ", RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath, " file array ", fileArray, " file array length ", fileArray.length, " fullFilepath ", newFilepath);

        await RNFS.copyFile(uri, newFilepath);

        try {
            var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('FILES');
            if(value !== null){
                console.log("existing data");
            } else {
                value = "{}";
            }

            var rString = randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

            var json = JSON.parse(value);

            json[rString] = {"file_path": newFilepath, "name": rString, "id": rString, "analyzed": false, "analysis": {}};

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);

            // console.log("update file: FILES " + jsonString);

            await AsyncStorage.setItem("FILES", jsonString);



            navigation.navigate('Home', {refresh: true});
        } catch (error) {
        console.error("failed to start recording", error);
        }
    }

    randomString = (length, chars) => {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        return result;
    }
  
    return (
        <Layout style={styles.container}>
            <Button
            onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
            >
                {recording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
            </Button>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding these line in your info.plist file

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description of why you require the use of the microphone</string>
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description of why you require the use of the speech recognition</string>
```

Your info.plist file should look like this

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
...
  <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Description of why you require the use of the microphone</string>
  <key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Description of why you require the use of the speech recognition</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```